# How can I restrict django PasswordResetView from redirecting to PasswordResetDoneView after submission of email?

Tags: django, django-forms, django-views

I don't want to redirect to PasswordResetDoneView after submitting the form in PasswordResetView instead I want to show a small modal in the PasswordResetView itself. How do I restrict from redirecting to PasswordResetDoneView?

Answer (score 0):

You can override the form_valid method or set a different success_url, depending on your needs. For example:

```
class PasswordReset(PasswordResetView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('your_modal_url')
```